# ESP8266 GET request code -1

Tags: esp8266, http

I've read several other posts but I still couldn't solve the issue. I'm trying to connect to a website which is HTTP (not HTTPS) but I always get code -1 as response. If I open the link in the browser it works well. Not sure what I am missing? Here's my full code:

```
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <esp8266wifi.h>

const char* ssid = "";
const char* password = "";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {

    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("Connecting..");

  }
}

void loop() {

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    HTTPClient http;
    http.begin("www.francescosoave.com/blind/getTime.php");
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    int httpCode = http.GET();

    Serial.print("HTTP CODE: ");
    Serial.println(httpCode);

    if(httpCode > 0){
      String payload = http.getString();
      Serial.print("PAYLOAD: ");
      Serial.println(payload);
    }

    http.end();
  }

  delay(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You omitted the protocol part of the url. [The HttpClient implementation](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/src/ESP8266HTTPClient.cpp) requires it.

Use `http.begin("http://www.francescosoave.com/blind/getTime.php");`

Do not use `Content-type` header. You do not send any content.

Turn-on debug in Tools menu. Set Debug Port to Serial and Debug Level to HTTP_CLIENT to see the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

to add an additional point to @juraj answer these are the `HTTP` code for various errors written in `ESP8266HTTPClient.h`

```
#define HTTPCLIENT_DEFAULT_TCP_TIMEOUT (5000)

/// HTTP client errors
#define HTTPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_FAILED   (-1)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_SEND_HEADER_FAILED  (-2)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_SEND_PAYLOAD_FAILED (-3)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED       (-4)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_LOST     (-5)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_NO_STREAM           (-6)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_NO_HTTP_SERVER      (-7)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_TOO_LESS_RAM        (-8)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_ENCODING            (-9)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_STREAM_WRITE        (-10)
#define HTTPC_ERROR_READ_TIMEOUT        (-11)
```

`-1` usually indicate `bad URL` or bad `wifi connection`

Comment: -1 means that `connect` failed. in this case because of the wrong port used because of the missing protocol part